# Binding a Textbox to a property in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, properties, dependency-properties

I have a Textbox in a User Control i'm trying to update from my main application but when I set the textbox.Text property it doesnt display the new value (even though textbos.Text contains the correct data). I am trying to bind my text box to a property to get around this but I dont know how, here is my code -

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
outputPanel.Text = outputText;
```

**OutputPanel.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             Text="{Binding <!--?????--> }"/>  <!-- I want to bind this to the Text Propert in OutputPanel.xmal.cs -->
```

**OutputPanel.xaml.cs**

```
 namespace Controls
{
public partial class OutputPanel : UserControl
{
    private string text;

    public TextBox Textbox
    {
        get {return textbox;}
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }

    public OutputPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = "test";
        textbox.Text = Text;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set a DataContext in some parent of the TextBox, for example:

```
<UserControl Name="panel" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=panel}">...
```

Then the binding will be:

```
Text="{Binding Text}"
```

And you shouldn't need this - referring to specific elements from code behind is usually bad practice:

```
public TextBox Textbox
{
    get {return textbox;}
}
```

Comment: <TextBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=[YOUR_TEXTBOX_NAME]}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>

Answer (score 8):

I hope this example will help you.

1) Create `UserControl`.

2) Add to XAML    `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.HeaderText}"></TextBlock>`

3) In the code behind of that `UserControl` add

> ```
> public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
>
>     {
>         public string HeaderText { set; get; } // Add this line
>
>         public MyUserControl()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>
>             DataContext = this; // And add this line
>         }
>     }
> ```

4) Outside of the control and let's say in the `MainWindow Load` event you have to do like

> this.gdMain = new MyUserControl{ HeaderText = "YES" };

Answer (score 0):

If your are starting to bind properties I suggest you check some articles on MVVM. 
This is a very powerful architecture you can use on WPF. I found it very useful in my projects.
Check this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).