# How to call a method in c# class with parameters set in WPF user control textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Having a main c#  class `CtrlMain`  with  method `testForm` it opens a WPF form (`testFormCtrl`)that shows a textbox and assigns a variable `Xmin` with the value introduced on textbox.

I want to execute method `wantToExe` from opened wpf user control with value introduced on textbox as a parameter

Here is what I have:

```
public partial class CtrlMain : UserControl
{
    int    mCounter;
    double firstPos;
    double[] currentBounds;
    //ETC..

    //constructor and class methods


    //this opens a user control
        static void testForm()
        {
            GenericWindow goWin;
            testFormCtrl mytestFormCtrl = new testFormCtrl();
            goWin = new GenericWindow(App.Current.MainWindow, mytestFormCtrl);
            goWin.Title = "test";
            goWin.ShowDialog();
        }


        //how to call this method with parameter of textbox?
        public  double wantToExe(double externalX){

            double result;

             //DO SOME COMPUTING 
            return result;

        }



}
```

the testFormCtrl xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="testFormCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Height="300">
            <Grid>
                <GroupBox Header="Location" Height="93" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,3,0,0" Name="GBoxGridDefinition" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="624">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" Name="TblockXmin" Text="Xmin:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" />
                        <TextBox Name="TextBoxXmin" Height="20" Width="89"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="59,9,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Xmin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" >
                        </TextBox>
                        <telerik:RadButton Content="Execute X" IsEnabled="True" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,9,0,0" Name="ButtonExecuteX" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Vista" />                        
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and c# code is

```
public partial class testFormCtrl : UserControl
    {
        double gnXmin;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public double Xmin
        {
            get { return gnXmin; }
            set
            {
                gnXmin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Xmin");
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(string lcProperty)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(lcProperty));
            }
        }  

        public testFormCtrl ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void ButtonExecuteX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //how to call CtrlMain.wantToExe(Xmin) ???
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call that method from other class, I can not make it static....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new constructor for your `testFormCtrl` class that accepts `CtrlMain` as a parameter:

```
private CtrlMain _caller;

public testFormCtrl(CtrlMain caller)
    : this()
{
    _caller = caller;
}
```

Then you can just invoke its methods:

```
private void ButtonExecuteX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(_caller != null) caller.wantToExe(Xmin);
}
```

Remember to pass the instance of `CtrlMain` in your `testForm` method:

```
static void testForm()
    {
        GenericWindow goWin;
        testFormCtrl mytestFormCtrl = new testFormCtrl(this); //use the new constructor
        goWin = new GenericWindow(App.Current.MainWindow, mytestFormCtrl);
        goWin.Title = "test";
        goWin.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Other question is Xmin is 0, and is not getting value entered on text box, do you know what would be the reason?

Comment: That's another question, anyway try to set the DataContext of your control. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032602/binding-a-textbox-to-a-property-in-wpf)